# How to get phone number from string?

Tags: objective-c

I want to extract the phone number from a NSString.

For ex: In the string Nandu @ +91-(123)-456-7890, I want to extract +91-(123)-456-7890.

I have tried code like,

```
NSString *myString = @"Nandu @ +91-(123)-456-7890";
NSString *myRegex = @"\\d{2}+\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:myRegex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];

NSString *phoneNumber = nil;
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    phoneNumber = [myString substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumber);
} else {
    NSLog(@"No phone number found");
}
```

how can I get phone number with +91 also.

Comment: You’ll want to use the NSRegularExpression class.

Comment: I'm using NSRegularExpression class but how to define the +91-()

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex pattern
`(\+\d{2}-\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}-\d{4})`

https://regexr.com/3qcsi

Answer (score 1):

Using `NSCharacterSet` you can get your output. see below code and let me know if you have any query then.

```
NSString *originalString = @"Nandu @ +91-(123)-456-7890";

NSString *cleanedString = [[originalString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", cleanedString); //+91-(123)-456-7890
```

Comment: if it is my original string is @"Nandu 1year old baby and his ph: @ +91-(123)-456-7890";
how can I write the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
 NSString *originalString = @"Nandu @ +91-(123)-456-7890";    
    NSArray *arrayWithTwoStrings = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    NSString *mobileNumberstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@",[arrayWithTwoStrings objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog (@"%@",mobileNumberstring);
```